# Facebook Open Graph object variable name appearing in action post

Tags: facebook-opengraph

After successfully posting my open graph action, the action appears just fine. But in the text, the last thing listed is my object variable name with a colon and then either the link to the object, which displays the title or full url link. SInce this is a bit difficult to explain, I created a screen shot:

[image: See annotations in this screen shot in red]

The name of my open graph object variable here is "venue" . The venue returned from my server is actually correct. I checked the link just in case again using the debug tool and had no errors. The issue is, It should not be displaying there.

Is this issue happening because my open graph action isn't approved yet? (I'm not done)

When it does happen, I notice all my open graph actions posted are shown in the same way. But then, other times, it will be fine. I will check tomorrow and see if it's still happening but wanted to see if anyone had any insight on what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally. There's an option to hide the object from the news feed.

[image: Hide object from news feed]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but if I understand it correctly, it's to do with the captions. Click on Edit Captions under the Story's details section, it will allow you to set what appears in the next few lines.

So you could do something like

Venue: {song.venue}

This is, of course, assuming that you want to show the venue. If not, your solution works :)